# write a typescript .d.ts type definition down node_module folder

Tags: typescript, .d.ts

I need to write a .d.ts file for an external (npm) library. I am using typescript 3.

The imports I need are:

```js
import fakedb from 'fake-indexeddb'; //sorted
// second import I would like:
import dbKeyRange from 'fake-indexeddb/lib/FDBKeyRange'
```

from types/fake-indexeddb.d.ts:

```
export = index;
declare const index: IDBFactory;
```

How do I write a file for the second import from the library I would like(`fake-indexeddb/lib/FDBKeyRange` - an `IDBKeyRange`)?

**Edit**
while the answer by Juraj Kocan is logically what i have to put in the .d.ts file, the question is what do I have to name the file so the debugger and transpiler find the file when I write `import dbKeyRange from 'fake-indexeddb/lib/FDBKeyRange'` - it is obvious how it finds the *types/fake-indexeddb.d.ts* file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add whole name to declaration

```
declare module 'fake-indexeddb/lib/FDBKeyRange' {
  class dbKeyRange {}
  export default dbKeyRange
}
```

edit

there are some rules for declarations.
add type rootes in tsconfig

```
 "typeRoots": [
  "./node_modules/@types",
  "./whateveryouwant/types"
],
```

or other path it does not matter. Just has to be defined in ts config
then add folder with name of your module.
in this folder add index.d.ts

```
--src
  --types
    --fake-indexeddb
      --index.d.ts
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I put ```import dbKeyRange from 'fake-indexeddb/lib/FDBKeyRange'``` the transpiler & debugger cannot find the type definition file (I have named it FDBKeyRange.d.ts) - I will add a question edit.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually mapped the folder path under my types directory, and that worked. final path to the definition file was:

```
types/fake-indexeddb/lib/FDBKeyRange.d.ts
```

with the definition in that file.