# How to solve the "Could not find a declaration file for module" error using my own declaration file?

Tags: typescript, .d.ts

I have a test project in which I'm testing type definition files. The project has one file called `index.ts` which looks like this:

```
import i18nFu = require("gettext.js");
```

The **gettext.js** package was installed using Node.js like this: `npm install gettext.js`

VS Code displays the following error message for the line above:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'gettext.js'.
>
> 'SOME_PATH/gettext.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>
> Try 'npm install @types/gettext.js' if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing "declare module 'gettext.js';"

Installing the `@types/gettext.js` module does fix the problem. But I'm curious so I didn't stop there. I removed the `@types/gettext.js` module again and tried to create the declaration file myself.

I create a subfolder called `types/gettext.js` in my project's folder and copied the content of the old `node_modules/@types/gettext.js` folder into it. I also added a `typeRoots` entry to my `tsconfig.json` file so it looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["ES2017"],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "strict": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": ["./types", "./node_modules/@types"],
    },
    "files": ["test.ts"]
}
```

But the error message won't disappear. Replacing the content of the `types/gettext.js/index.d.ts` file ([which you can see here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/gettext.js/index.d.ts)) with `declare module 'gettext.js'` (as suggested by the error message) does remove the error. But that is not a solution for having types. What am I missing?

**PS:** I'm not interested in work around hack solutions like using `ts-ignore` or setting `noImplicitAny` to `false`.

Comment: If I remember correctly, all you would need to to is add a file called `gettext.js.d.ts`somewhere in your `src`-directory, and it will be picked up by VS Code and TS.

Comment: @Greg: Thanks. I've just tried that and it has no effect.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting the `baseUrl` compiler option. Interestingly I don't need the `typeRoots` option at all now to compile and run successfully. This is the new `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["ES2017"],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "strict": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "baseUrl": "./types"
    },
    "files": ["tests.ts"]
}
```

I hope this helps someone running into the same problem.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and the `baseUrl` doesn't seem to help. Any ideas?

Comment: @Bassem not really. I think you should post a new question with all the information you have and include a link to this question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file with d.ts(html2pdf.js.d.ts) and add the following code `declare module 'html2pdf.js';` and it works